# "It provides opportunity for" vs. "It provides the opportunity for"

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, grammaticality, articles, grammaticality-in-context

I came across this expression in this newspaper [article](https://www.huffpost.com/entry/social-media-is-an-equali_b_5490792):

> "It *provides opportunity for* a small nonprofit organization to be
> competitive with a major brand with huge marketing budget."

I was wondering whether it is instead more correct and/or appropriate the usage of an article before *opportunity*:

> It *provides **an** opportunity for* a small nonprofit organization to [...].

To me, it sounds weird (incorrect?) using the singular noun *opportunity* without any article before it.

Do you have any feedback about it? Is it correct? Or maybe just used despite incorrect?

Comment: Newspapers have limited space or word limits, and so they customarily omit articles/words when the meaning is clear ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Macmillan dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/opportunity) notes that *opportunity* is either countable *or uncountable*, giving the example:

> **opportunity for:** The job pays well, but there’s not much opportunity for career advancement.

It does sound a bit odd to use it this way without more qualifying words ("It provides *plenty of* opportunity for..."), but it's valid.

Comment: So, the "issue" is just that in those cases "opportunity" is used as uncountable.

Comment: @Gabrer Exactly. The original newspaper quote is analogous to "it provides [some] opportunity," without specifying how much.